# How can I break down a large presenter in the Viper design pattern into smaller pieces?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, viper-architecture

Presenter classes in some modules of the project I'm working on have exceeded 5000 lines. I'm struggling to manage the logic and unit tests here. How can I effectively break down an inflated presenter in the Viper design pattern into smaller pieces?

Comment: In VIPER there's a 1:1 relationship between the _View_ and the _Presenter_. A "View" is usually a screen composed of a UIViewController, possible Child View Controllers and all their UIViews. The presenter receives the model data which it only needs to prepare for rendering, i.e. _transform_ it for rendering. Otherwise it delegates any other tasks.Having 5.000 lines of code for this is very unusual. There is likely an issue with the design and the presenter does too many things. Also, VIPER is _extremely_ heavy on boilerplate, scales very poorly and it is very difficult to support UI flows.